# .htaccess: Redirect root url to subdirectory, but keep root URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a site in a subdirectory and would like the site to appear as if it's in the root.

I used the below Mod_Rewrite code to get the site root to redirect to the subdirectory, but I would like the folder the files are held in to not appear.

currently: `www.example.com/sitefiles/content/`

Would like: `www.example.com/content`

Thanks

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /sitefiles/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /sitefiles/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Are you able to change httpd.conf on that server?

Answer (score 2):

If it **needs** to be done via .htaccess and mod_rewrite, then use this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitefiles/
RewriteRule (.*) /sitefiles/$1 [L]
```

1. Since you do not explicitly specify the page when website root will be hit, then there is no need for this line: `RewriteRule ^$ /sitefiles/ [L]`
2. You need to add condition for your main rewrite rule to prevent rewrite loop (when already rewritten URL gets rewritten again): `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitefiles/`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the directory should have no reason to appear in any listing, and that mod_rewrite you posted should allow you to do as you said. Still, I would go about it a different way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ sitefiles/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ sitefiles/$1 [L]
```

Hope this works.